# module.exports function is not a function

Tags: javascript, import, webpack, export, webpack-2

I'm trying to require an endpoints.js file into my webpack.config.js

#### Expected

endpoints.js gets required correctly then sets a custom api file depending on the `process.env.NODE_ENV`

#### Results

[image]

`const api = endpoints(process.env.NODE_ENV);`

> TypeError: endpoints is not a function

---

## Webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const dist = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const src = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");
const endpoints = require("./src/endpoints");
const api = endpoints(process.env.NODE_ENV);

console.log('webpack endpoints', endpoints);
console.log('webpack api', api);
```

---

## endpoints.js

```
module.exports = {
    endpoints: function(env) {
        let prefix = env === 'development' ? 'http://localhost' : '';

        return {
            "login": `${prefix}/app/api/login`
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried the following, but got an **Unexpected token export**

```
export default function endpoints(env) {
    let prefix = env === 'development' ? 'http://localhost' : '';

    return {
        "login": `${prefix}/app/api/login`
    }
};
```

Comment: Spelling? Should it not be `endpoints`? (`enpoints` missing `d`)

Comment: Sorry, I had fixed the spelling and it still didn't work, updating my question now.

Comment: Do you use Babel so you can export ? Commonjs for module.exports ?

Comment: How are you generating that code error? That's a fancy background.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm using iterm2 :) with a transparent background, and I have some space background coming through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah I was using module.exports wrong, however it looked correct according [to this site](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/).

This is how I needed to use module.exports to export out my endpoints function.

```
function endpoints(env) {
    let prefix = env === 'development' ? 'http://localhost' : '';

    return {
        "login": `${prefix}/app/api/login`
    }
}

module.exports = endpoints;
```